# What declares the end of a variable in memory?

Tags: memory, binary

In memory, how does the CPU know when a variable is over.

Lets say you have a string:

```
x = 'Hi';
```

And it's stored to memory. 
When the CPU is executing the program, how does it know when the data in that memory address is over.

In binary, x would be stored as:

```
Byte 1:1001000
Byte 2:1101001
```

What tells the CPU that byte of data is over?
I am aware of Null Terminators, but in Assembly and lower (IE; Machine Code) what declares the end of that variable?